# The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the argument. A string or numeric expression was used

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and I use SSAS.

When I write the query below,

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] - [Measures].[Internet Standard Product Cost] ON COLUMNS,
[Customer].[Country].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I get this error

> Executing the query ...
>
> The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric 
>   expression was used.
>
> Execution complete

what is my problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An axis expression must contain a set of tuples that are defining the shape of the result; you are using a value instead. You should use a calculated measure as following :

```
with member [Measures].[Profit] as 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] - [Measures].[Internet Standard Product Cost]
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Profit] ON COLUMNS,
  [Customer].[Country].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Have a look to this [page](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/select_statement.html) for a gentle introduction to MDX select statement.